# Wygwam 3.3.1 Add an <input> button

Tags: wygwam

Since Wygwam 3 was released it has not had the form elements button reintroduced. I am in need of some guidance on how to add the button back for our editors, more specifically the  field.

I have looked into adding plugins to CKeditor, and it appears I have followed the instructions but the integration with expression engine the button will not show.

I contacted Brandon Kelly about this back in September and he indicated the following...

> We removed those plugins for Wygwam 3.0, along with some others that were very rarely used, to cut down on Wygwam's overall file size. The next update will come with a way to bring them back if you really need them, but for now, the only way to get them is to go back to Wygwam 2.x.

The update to Wygwam 3.2 appears to have added this functionality, but the documention is unlear to me.

> Wygwam 3.2
>
> Released on Oct 1, 2013
>
> Added the wygwam_tb_groups, wygwam_tb_label_overrides, and wygwam_tb_combos extension hooks, making it possible for other extensions to add new toolbar buttons to Wygwam’s toolbar configurator.
>
> http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/changelog.html

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Still looking for a solution on this if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with adding back in the save icon as my users had become accustomed to using it.The icon was available as a plugin for ck-editor and got it working after a bit of a battle .The documentation on how to do so isn't very good and is difficult to follow.
There is a lot involved in this in this so it might be best if i can email you what i have done and you can just copy it and make a few adjustments for your plugin

Comment: I'm down with that, thank you for your help... mmcbrien@savannahchristian.com

Comment: can you shoot me an email when you get a chance so I can mark this as answered?

Comment: Trying again - please contact me if you can, i would really like to know how you accomplished this :D

Comment: Hi Mike , I emailed you last week  about this , maybe check your spam folder

Comment: I did not get it, please try mikeamcbrien (at) gmail.com

Thank you!

Comment: Hi mike I will do that,just in case you dont get it I have posted a similar answer to another problem here http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/22280/adding-ckeditor-plugins-to-wygwam