# Wygwam Ordered List Properties

Tags: wygwam, ckeditor

Is it possible to access the ordered list properties field in Wygwam?  It is not there by default and I don't see any options in the Editor Configurations dropdown that would add it.

This is what I am trying to do...

http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/creating-alphabetical-list-in-ckeditor

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it is through an addon from ckeditor .
The plugin you want is here

http://ckeditor.com/addon/liststyle

Instructions from the pixel and tonic site on how to add a plugin to Wygwam

http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/developers/ckeditor_plugins.html

It not very clear so here are more detailed instructions

[Adding CKEditor Plugins to Wygwam](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/22280/adding-ckeditor-plugins-to-wygwam/24001#24001)

Thanks
Brian